# Kill a Java API operation without stopping the application

Tags: java

I am trying to stop an API operation in java, by which I mean to stop a process which is executed as part of the api call. My api looks like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/startProcess",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public ResponseEntity<String> startProcess(
  @Parameter(@RequestBody testBody)
        ) {
          
         String somekindofID = testservice.startProcess();
         return new ResponseEntity<>(someKindofID, HTTPStatus.OK);
        }



@RequestMapping(value = "/testPID",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> TestPID(
            @Parameter(name = "somekindofID",required = true) @Valid @RequestBody String somekindofID)
    ) {
      
     //get the ID from the above api and kill the running process
    }



public String startProcess() {      
   long pid = 0;
    new Thread(()-> {
        try {
                int exitCode = startProcessBuilderwithCommand(); //starts a processbuilder with batch file
                if (exitCode != 0) {
                     return;
                }else{                        
                   pid=consumer.initiateConsumer(); -> this is the process which needs to stop
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
    }).start();

    return pid;
}
```

Now, I have tried using Java 9's `ProcessHandle.current().pid()`
but it give the PID of the Java application itself, which if I use to taskkill would terminate the entire application.

Is there a way to get an ID or something from just the api operation, so that I can terminate it without terminating the entire Java application?

In Other words I would like to end the background process without killing the application.

P.s. the method `testservice.startProcess()` returns an ID of the initiateconsumer() method which I am trying to kill without killing the application

Comment: Well where is the code that starts the process?  That is not how APIs work.  You either need to have the API return a PID and then the caller can call another API to stop it, but this sounds like a design problem

Comment: this is a protoype, I have an api which runs a process in a thread, which I plan to use to return an ID, and I can use this ID to stop the api process

Comment: Instead of describing parts of your code in a comment, why not add the code to the question. But try to provide it as a [mre] - the smallest amount of code which we can copy and run for ourselves, to recreate your scenario.

Comment: I have added the edited code which is reproducible.

Comment: so if you are returning the PID if the spawned process, you need to write another API to let the caller stop it?  That being said, killing a process in the middle of it doing work may result in unpredictable behavior.  Since we don't know what this process does, who knows what the results will be.

Comment: its not the process which I wish to kill, the consumer.initiateConsumer(); starts a kafka consumer which runs in the background. And I intend to stop that consumer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you need the following.

1. the Consumer started with initiateConsumer() needs to contain a mechanism that
   it uses to check whether it has been stopped by another process.
2. a way of identifying which consumer to stop.

**@Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/startProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Integer> startProcessPost(@RequestBody String testBody) {

int somekindofID = testservice.startProcess();
return new ResponseEntity<>(somekindofID, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/testPID", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ResponseEntity<Void> TestPID(@RequestParam(name = "somekindofID", required = true) int somekindofID) {
    Consumer.killConsumer(somekindofID);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

**Consumer**

```
public class Consumer {

    private static Map<Integer, Consumer> runningConsumers = new HashMap<>();
    
    boolean running;
    
    public int initiateConsumer() {
        running = true;
        int hashCode = hashCode();
        runningConsumers.put(hashCode, this);
        // pass the work into a Runnable
        return hashCode;
    }
    
    public static void killConsumer(int hashCode) {
        Consumer consumerToBeKilled = runningConsumers.get(hashCode);
        consumerToBeKilled.running = false;
        
    }
    
    private void consumerActivity() {
        while(running) {
            // keep working
        }
        // take me out of the Map
        int hashCode = hashCode();
        runningConsumers.remove(hashCode);

    }

}
```

**TestService**

```
public class TestService {

    final Consumer consumer = new Consumer();

    public int startProcess() {
        final int[] pidHolder = new int[] {-1}; // because only finals can be passed to threads
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int exitCode = startProcessBuilderwithCommand(); // starts a processbuilder with batch file
                    if (exitCode != 0) {
                        return;
                    } else {
                        pidHolder[0] = consumer.initiateConsumer(); // -> this is the process which needs to stop
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

        return pidHolder[0];
        
    }
```

Note that stopping a Thread from the outside is even more difficult - [java-thread-stop](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-stop) - also needs something to watch from within.